# Editing TFS release management definitions

Tags: tfs, ms-release-management

In TFS 2015 update 2, is there a way to copy release definition steps from one environment to another, or from one def to another, or within an environment (to make a clone)? What about multiple selection? Drag and drop only works within an environment, and Ctrl+drag doesn't seem to be supported.

In TFS 2013 Windows-based release client, it was perfectly possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have TFS 2015.2 to test your scenario, but I have tested in TFS 2015.3. In TFS 2015.3, you can clone environment, but can't clone release definition. Check the screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

I also tested in the newest TFS15, you can both clone environment and clone release definition. Check the screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

So, you can consider upgrading your TFS, then you are be able to clone environment.